# Punctuation with complete or incomplete list of items

Tags: punctuation, lists

Here's a situation:

> John, Anne, Jake, Pete...they are all from the same class.

Is there any way to punctuate this sentence without using the ellipsis? Is an "and" necessary before the last item (here, Pete) in this kind of a list? What would be the best way to punctuate this sentence in formal writing, e.g. a book manuscript?

Comment: [*And* certainly isn't necessary](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124480/lists-without-and) -- there are lots of posts mentioning [*asyndeton*](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=asyndeton). You might use a colon to separate the list from its description.

Comment: Are you unfamiliar with the use of *etc*?

Comment: @BlessedGeek Sorry but I don't think etc. is necessary here. The list is complete.

Comment: Make up your mind. Is the list complete or not? If complete, use an *and* before the last item. If not, use *etc* after the last comma.

Comment: This is more about the ellipsis than "and" or "etc".

Comment: @BlessedGeek I don't know how else to say this: The list is COMPLETE.